# Getting a value within multiple rows with same id in dataframe

Tags: pandas

This is my data frame

```
d = {'id': [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4] ,
 'a_code': ['abc', 'abclm', 'pqr', 'pqren', 'lmn', 'lmnre', 'xyznt', 'gvn', 'gvnwe', 'trenv'], 
 'a_type': ['CP','CO','CP','CO','CP','CP','CO','CP','RT','CO'],
 'z_code': ['abclm', 'wedvg', 'pqren', 'unfdc', 'lmnre','wqrtn','hgbvcx','gvnwe','cnotn', 'wxbnt'],
 'z_type': ['CO', 'CO', 'CO','CO','CP','CO','RT','RT','CO','RT']}

df= pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I am trying to compare across multiple rows with the same id and return value of `z_code` for the row where  `z_type` has a value other than CP for the first time.

Basically, I am having location transfers in each row, that's what A to Z means and soon as type changes from CP to something else on Z side, I want that `z_code` value for that `id`.

Anytime I have a_type as `CP` -> z_type as CO, I want to return z_code.

Output:

`id   a_type    a_code     z_type     z_code
 1      CP        abc        CO        abclm
 2      CP        pqr        CO        pqren
 3      CP       lmnre       CO        wqrtn
 4      CP        gvn        CO        cnotn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter `CO` values by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then I get first rows by `id` by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print (df[df['z_type'].eq('CO')])
   id a_code a_type z_code z_type
0   1    abc     CP  abclm     CO
1   1  abclm     CO  wedvg     CO
2   2    pqr     CP  pqren     CO
3   2  pqren     CO  unfdc     CO
5   3  lmnre     CP  wqrtn     CO

df1 = (df[df['z_type'].eq('CO')]
       .drop_duplicates('id')
       .rename(columns={'z_code':'code'})[['id','code']])
print (df1)
   id   code
0   1  abclm
2   2  pqren
5   3  wqrtn
```

Comment: I am not getting desired output , i have edited dataframe and added comment as well

Comment: @MurtazaHaji- So there is no `CO` values, but possible `' CO'`, with whitespaces? Because for me working perfectly with sample data

Comment: I have updated the question, can you plzz check it out?

Comment: Can I set `or` condition in `eq`? `df[df['z_type'].eq('CO' or 'RT')]`, this only uses the first value and returns all rows with that.

Comment: @Murtaza Haji yop, for or is used `isin` method in pandas like `df[df['z_type'].isin(['CO', 'RT'] )]`