# Filtering row by comparing multiple column across multiple rows for the same id

Tags: pandas

This is a follow-up from the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61455533/getting-a-value-within-multiple-rows-with-same-id-in-dataframe/61455606#comment108754992_61455606).

This is my dataframe:

```
d = {'id': [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4] ,
     'a_code': ['abc', 'abclm', 'pqr', 'pqren', 'lmn', 'lmnre', 'xyznt', 'gvn', 'gvnwe', 'trenv'], 
     'a_type': ['CP','CO','CP','CO','CP','CP','CO','CP','RT','CO'],
     'z_code': ['abclm', 'wedvg', 'pqren', 'unfdc', 'lmnre','wqrtn','hgbvcx','gvnwe','cnotn', 'wxbnt'],
     'z_type': ['CO', 'CO', 'CO','CO','CP','CO','RT','RT','CO','CO']}

df= pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I want to keep track of the first occurrence of `CP` in `a_type` and return `a_code` and `z_code` when the value in z_type is `CO`

For eg:
In row 7 of df, I will pick the  `a_code` since it matches with `CP` in `a_type`, but I will pick `z_code` from row 8 , since `z_type` is `CO`
Check output when id=4

Output:

```
 id   a_type    a_code     z_type     z_code
 1      CP        abc        CO        abclm
 2      CP        pqr        CO        pqren
 3      CP        lmn        CO        wqrtn
 4      CP        gvn        CO        cnotn
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df2 = (df[df['z_type'].eq('CO')]
       .drop_duplicates('id')[['id','z_type','z_code']])
df1 = (df[df['a_type'].eq('CP')]
       .drop_duplicates('id')[['id','a_type','a_code']])     

df = df1.merge(df2, on='id')
print (df)
   id a_type a_code z_type z_code
0   1     CP    abc     CO  abclm
1   2     CP    pqr     CO  pqren
2   3     CP    lmn     CO  wqrtn
3   4     CP    gvn     CO  cnotn
```

Comment: How are we ensuring that the final `CP ` is picked in `df1`, because doesnt drop_duplicates always pick first value and ignore others?

Comment: @MurtazaHaji - there are 2 possible states - If exist value `CP` for `a_type` per group at least one then get expected row, if not exist but exist CO for `z_code` get misisng values. But not sure if 100% understand, if possible, can you change sample data for this problem?

Comment: Works perfectly on my dataset. Incase I find any outliers I will post. For now I think this logic works great!!

Comment: I actually came back to this question , because I wanted first occurance of CP , but by accident we were already doing that. I have updated the dataframe and output accordingly.